# Using positional arguments in functional tests has been deprecated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm getting this warning when I run rspec:-

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Using positional arguments in functional tests has been deprecated,
in favor of keyword arguments, and will be removed in Rails 5.1.

Deprecated style:
get :show, { id: 1 }, nil, { notice: "This is a flash message" }

New keyword style:
get :show, params: { id: 1 }, flash: { notice: "This is a flash message" },
  session: nil # Can safely be omitted.
 (called from block (4 levels) in <top (required)> at /home/user/organization/fooobarr/spec/controllers/contacts_controller_spec.rb:13)
```

This is my controller spec:-

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe ContactsController, :type => :controller do

  describe "#create" do
    it "sends an email when message is valid" do
      expect{
        post :create, message: attributes_for(:message)
      }.to change{ ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.count }.by(1)
    end

    it "does not send email when message is invalid" do
      expect{
        post :create, message: {subject: "", name: "",
                                email:"", content: ""}
      }.to change{ ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.count }.by(0)
    end
  end
end
```

Throws the error on line 13 and 19.

I'm not sure how to change the code I have so that the warning no longer appears.

Comment: The deprecation message is very clear, what is exactly you dont understand? Have you tried to rewrite code in new style?

Comment: @Зелёный if you look at their code example, you'll find that they are already using keyword arguments, so that there seems to be no reason for the deprecation message.

Comment: @janfoeh there is no such thing like `message`, there is only `params, headers, env, xhr`, so I assume his is not trying.

Comment: @Зелёный well there you go, you've just answered their question.

Comment: got it to work after carefully going over the suggestion. Thanks @Зелёный

Answer (score 20):

For future reference you can also fix these (in bulk!) with Rubocop's Autofix feature:

http://rubocop.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cops_rails/#railshttppositionalarguments

```
bundle exec rubocop --rails --only HttpPositionalArguments --auto-correct
```

Remember to set `TargetRailsVersion: 5.0` or higher in the Rubocop config, to enable that cop.

Comment: This was previously not working for me for no obvious reason. I discovered that having a local `spec/.rubocop.yml` file (even if empty) was somehow disabling this cop or causing it to fail. I've submitted it as an issue to Rubocop at https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/issues/5576. To work around it, I deleted the file, ran the autocorrect above, and checked out the local config I deleted. Hopefully this helps someone else.

Answer (score 16):

Thanks @samjewell for the hint.
it seems this syntax is now outdated, I could not use the --rails parameters.

Here is the updated way to achieve this today

in your Gemfile, use `gem 'rubocop-rails'` instead of `rubocop`.

in your `.rubocop.yml` add the require and relevant Rails version

```
require: rubocop-rails
Rails:
  Enabled: true
AllCops:
   TargetRubyVersion: 2.4
   TargetRailsVersion: 5.0
```

Then run

`bundle exec rubocop --only Rails/HttpPositionalArguments -a`

to fix those deprecation warnings automatically

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I got it work with the following:-

```
  describe "#create" do
    it "sends an email when message is valid" do
      expect{
        post :create, params: {message: attributes_for(:message)}
      }.to change{ ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.count }.by(1)
    end

    it "does not send email when message is invalid" do
      expect{
        post :create, params: {message: {subject: "", name: "",
                                email:"", content: ""}}
      }.to change{ ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.count }.by(0)
    end
  end
end
```